# How to remove part of URL

Tags: php, url, preg-match

Let's say my URL is this:

```
http://example.com/forum/index.php?topic=53.msg251#msg251
```

This part here, I can't figure out how to remove:

```
.msg251#msg251
```

I did try though, I'm not sure if I am even close to doing it right.

```
 $linkraw = $items->link;
 $linkpattern = '/^.msg247#msg247/';
 $link = preg_match($linkpattern, $linkraw);
```

What is the correct way of doing this? I am trying to learn.

Comment: You could use  http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: Do you want to match or remove?

Comment: String functions strrpos and substr are enough for this task. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String functions [strrpos](http://php.net/strrpos) and [substr](http://php.net/substr) are enough for this task. And its surely faster.

```
 $link = substr($linkraw, 0, strrpos($linkraw, "."))
```

#### Explanation:

1. `strrpos` finds the position of `.` from the end of the string.
2. `substr` extracts a sub string till the position of `.` found in previous step.

#### When this will work?

Works on `http://example.com/forum/index.php?topic=53.msg251#msg251`
Works on `http://example.com/forum/index.php?topic=53.new#new`
But **not** on `http://example.com/forum/index.php?topic=53.msg251#msg251.new#new`

Comment: Could you explain what's going on when this is applied?

Comment: Wouldn't this still work if '.new#new' was at the end of the URL instead?

Comment: See my explanation. It'll find the last `.` Then split the string before that point. So if you add anything that has `.`. It'll not split at the newly appended `.`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove, use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$link = preg_replace('/\..*?$/', '', $linkraw);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple using the `http_build_url` function (requires PECL pecl_http >= 0.21.0).

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://example/forum/index.php?topic=53.msg251#msg251';
    echo http_build_url($url, null, HTTP_URL_STRIP_FRAGMENT);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

> "preg_match() returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be
>   either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because preg_match() will stop
>   searching after the first match. preg_match_all() on the contrary will
>   continue until it reaches the end of subject. preg_match() returns
>   FALSE if an error occurred."

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Preg_Match checks only if the pattern exists in the string. It doesn't remove something.

You can use str_replace() for replacing that part

```
$link = str_replace(".msg251#msg251", "", $linkraw);
```